# dynamic change class in section, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Document is ready. When scrolling the page is dynamic assigned class "visible" in "cd-section"

I need when id="container-3" assigned a class "visible" - container id="site" getting class .dark

My script does not work with dynamic change of the container class

```
<div id="site">
  <section class="itemListPrimary   cd-section visible" >1</section>
  <section class="itemListSecondary cd-section" id="container-0"></section>
  <section class="itemListSecondary cd-section" id="container-1"></section>
  <section class="itemListSecondary cd-section" id="container-2"></section>
  <section class="itemListSecondary cd-section" id="container-3"></section>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if ( jQuery('#container-03').hasClass('visible')) {
   jQuery('#site').addClass('dark');
  } else {
    jQuery('#site').removeClass('dark');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: better to use `toggleClass`

Comment: You will need to use a dom observer or trigger an event when the class is changed then use that event to assign the active class

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong - do you want to class `visible` to the section which is currently in a view port (visible to end user)? And when last container comes in view port then you want to add `dark` class to `#site`?

Comment: Better show a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2):

If the class changes when scrolling then probably you should use `scroll()` event to check every time the user scroll if the class `active` is assigned to the section then toggle class `dark` :

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
  if ( jQuery('#container-3').hasClass('active')) {
       jQuery('#site').addClass('dark');
  } else {
       jQuery('#site').removeClass('dark');
  }
});
```

Comment: what triggers the changes in the class for the cd-sections?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for something like this?

```
 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if(jQuery(".itemListSecondary.cd-section").hasClass("active")){
         jQuery("#site").toggleClass("dark");
        }
    });
```